# How to add balloons in OpenStreetMap?

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

How do I add balloons like those on Google Maps (such as the one shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wggvB.jpg)) into OpenStreetMap? This is my OpenStreetMap code below:

```
import org.osmdroid.DefaultResourceProxyImpl;
import org.osmdroid.ResourceProxy;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapController;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MyItemizedOverlay myItemizedOverlay = null;
  private MapController myMapController;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myMapController = mapView.getController();
    myMapController.setZoom(16);


    Drawable marker=getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_big_on);
    int markerWidth = marker.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int markerHeight = marker.getIntrinsicHeight();
    marker.setBounds(0, markerHeight, markerWidth, 0);

    ResourceProxy resourceProxy = new   
   DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());

    myItemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(marker, resourceProxy);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myItemizedOverlay);

    GeoPoint myPoint1 = new GeoPoint(24.893379000000000000, 67.028060900000010000);
    myItemizedOverlay.addItem(myPoint1, "myPoint1", "myPoint1");
    GeoPoint myPoint2 = new GeoPoint(24.824796300000000000, 67.031565699999990000);
    myItemizedOverlay.addItem(myPoint2, "myPoint2", "myPoint2");


  } 

}


import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.osmdroid.ResourceProxy;
import org.osmdroid.api.IMapView;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ItemizedOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.OverlayItem;

import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> overlayItemList = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable pDefaultMarker,
       ResourceProxy pResourceProxy) {
     super(pDefaultMarker, pResourceProxy);
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
     }

     public void addItem(GeoPoint p, String title, String snippet){
        OverlayItem newItem = new OverlayItem(title, snippet, p);
        overlayItemList.add(newItem);
        populate(); 
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onSnapToItem(int arg0, int arg1, Point arg2, IMapView arg3) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return false;
     }

     @Override
     protected OverlayItem createItem(int arg0) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return overlayItemList.get(arg0);
     }

     @Override
     public int size() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return overlayItemList.size();
     }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was with the same question and now I found a way:

1. Download the **osmbonuspack** here: https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/
2. Follow this code:

   ```
   ArrayList<ExtendedOverlayItem> overlayItemArray = new ArrayList<ExtendedOverlayItem>();

   ExtendedOverlayItem item = new ExtendedOverlayItem("Title, "Description, new GeoPoint(Double latitude, Double longitude), this);

   //creates a layer with ballons

   ItemizedOverlayWithBubble<ExtendedOverlayItem> poiMarkers = new ItemizedOverlayWithBubble<ExtendedOverlayItem>(this, overlayItemArray, mapView, new CustomMapInfoWindow(mapView));

   // add the layer
   mapView.getOverlays().add(poiMarkers);
   ```
3. Create a class called **CustomMapInfoWindow**:

   ```
   import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.overlays.DefaultInfoWindow;
   import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.overlays.ExtendedOverlayItem;
   import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;

   public class CustomMapInfoWindow extends DefaultInfoWindow {

       public CustomMapInfoWindow(MapView mapView) {
           super(R.layout.bonuspack_bubble, mapView);

       }

       @Override
       public void onOpen(ExtendedOverlayItem item) {
           super.onOpen(item);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Go to [OSMBONUSPACKDEMO REPOSITORY](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FOSMBonusPackDemo%2Fres%2Flayout) and get **bonuspack_bubble.xml** and the **drawables** into *drawable-mdpi* folder.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the osmbonuspack library, which is an add-on for osmdroid. It includes an overlay that will display popup balloons:

https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/